# MongoDB MapReduce causes "Error: error during query"

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I've got a collection with documents using a schema something like this (some members redacted):

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("539f41a95d1887b57ab78bea"),
    "answers" : {
        "ratings" : {
            "positivity" : [ 
                2, 
                3, 
                5
            ],
            "activity" : [ 
                4, 
                4, 
                3
            ],
    },
    "media" : [ 
        ObjectId("537ea185df872bb71e4df270"), 
        ObjectId("537ea185df872bb71e4df275"), 
        ObjectId("537ea185df872bb71e4df272")
    ]
}
```

In this schema, the first, second, and third `positivity` ratings correspond to the first, second, and third entries in the `media` array, respectively. The same is true for the `activity` ratings. I need to calculate statistics for the `positivity` and `activity` ratings with respect to their associated `media` objects across all documents in the collection. Right now, I'm doing so for the first entries with the following MapReduce setup:

```js
var mapFunction = function() {
    var activity = {
        sum: this.answers.ratings.activity[0],
        min: this.answers.ratings.activity[0],
        max: this.answers.ratings.activity[0],
        count: 1,
        diff: 0
    };

    var positivity = {
        sum: this.answers.ratings.positivity[0],
        min: this.answers.ratings.positivity[0],
        max: this.answers.ratings.positivity[0],
        count: 1,
        diff: 0
    };

    emit(this.media[0].str, {'activity': activity, 'positivity': positivity});
}

var reduceFunction = function(key, values) {

    var activityA = values[0].activity; // will reduce into here
    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {

        var activityB = values[i].activity; // will merge 'b' into 'a'

        // temp helpers
        var delta = activityA.sum/activityA.count - activityB.sum/activityB.count; // a.mean - b.mean
        var weight = (activityA.count * activityB.count)/(activityA.count + activityB.count);

        // do the reducing
        activityA.diff += activityB.diff + delta*delta*weight;
        activityA.sum += activityB.sum;
        activityA.count += activityB.count;
        activityA.min = Math.min(activityA.min, activityB.min);
        activityA.max = Math.max(activityA.max, activityB.max);
    }

    var positivityA = values[0].positivity; // will reduce into here
    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {

        var positivityB = values[i].positivity; // will merge 'b' into 'a'

        // temp helpers
        var delta = positivityA.sum/positivityA.count - positivityB.sum/positivityB.count; // a.mean - b.mean
        var weight = (positivityA.count * positivityB.count)/(positivityA.count + positivityB.count);

        // do the reducing
        positivityA.diff += positivityB.diff + delta*delta*weight;
        positivityA.sum += positivityB.sum;
        positivityA.count += positivityB.count;
        positivityA.min = Math.min(positivityA.min, positivityB.min);
        positivityA.max = Math.max(positivityA.max, positivityB.max);
    }

    return {'activity': activityA, 'positivity': positivityA};
}

var finalizeFunction = function(key, value) {
    value.activity.mean = value.activity.sum / value.activity.count;
    value.activity.population_variance = value.activity.diff / value.activity.count;
    value.activity.population_std = Math.sqrt(value.activity.population_variance);
    value.activity.sample_variance = value.activity.diff / (value.activity.count - 1);
    value.activity.sample_std = Math.sqrt(value.activity.sample_variance);

    value.positivity.mean = value.positivity.sum / value.positivity.count;
    value.positivity.population_variance = value.positivity.diff / value.positivity.count;
    value.positivity.population_std = Math.sqrt(value.positivity.population_variance);
    value.positivity.sample_variance = value.positivity.diff / (value.positivity.count - 1);
    value.positivity.sample_std = Math.sqrt(value.positivity.sample_variance);
    return value;
}

var limitingQuery = {'answers.ratings.activity':{$exists:true},'answers.ratings.positivity':{$exists:true}}
db.trials.mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction, {query: limitingQuery, finalize: finalizeFunction, out: {replace: 'base_ratings', db: 'tmp'}});
```

Using a small number of documents, this all works as I expect. When I run it against the entire collection, a few strange things happen. First, when I run `db.currentOp()`, I get the following output:

```js
{
        "inprog" : [
                {
                        "opid" : 2337,
                        "active" : true,
                        "secs_running" : 2787,
                        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong("2787597940"),
                        "op" : "query",
                        "ns" : "eim.trials",
                        "query" : {
                                "$msg" : "query not recording (too large)"
                        },
                        "planSummary" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "client" : "109.201.154.152:59939",
                        "desc" : "conn17",
                        "threadId" : "0x7ef89b022700",
                        "connectionId" : 17,
                        "locks" : {
                                "^" : "r",
                                "^eim" : "R"
                        },
                        "waitingForLock" : false,
                        "msg" : "m/r: (1/3) emit phase M/R: (1/3) Emit Progress: 8300/1 830000%",
                        "progress" : {
                                "done" : 8300,
                                "total" : 1
                        },
                        "numYields" : 1133,
                        "lockStats" : {
                                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                                        "r" : NumberLong("5075753298"),
                                        "w" : NumberLong(2274)
                                },
                                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                        "r" : NumberLong(243155328),
                                        "w" : NumberLong(131)
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        "opid" : 2480,
                        "active" : true,
                        "secs_running" : 2111,
                        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(2111502538),
                        "op" : "query",
                        "ns" : "eim.trials",
                        "query" : {
                                "$msg" : "query not recording (too large)"
                        },
                        "planSummary" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "client" : "109.201.154.192:61609",
                        "desc" : "conn23",
                        "threadId" : "0x7ef89ac1e700",
                        "connectionId" : 23,
                        "locks" : {
                                "^" : "r",
                                "^eim" : "R"
                        },
                        "waitingForLock" : false,
                        "msg" : "m/r: (1/3) emit phase M/R: (1/3) Emit Progress: 7952/1 795200%",
                        "progress" : {
                                "done" : 7952,
                                "total" : 1
                        },
                        "numYields" : 819,
                        "lockStats" : {
                                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                                        "r" : NumberLong("3399905661"),
                                        "w" : NumberLong(73184)
                                },
                                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                        "r" : NumberLong(406543723),
                                        "w" : NumberLong(145)
                                }
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

What's with the `Emit Progress` being greater than 100%? I know additional documents aren't being added to the collection while this is all running. And, `inprog.progress.done`is `8300` while `inprog.progress.total` is `1`. Huh?

What's worse, this operation eventually bails with the error:

```js
Error: error doing query: failed src/mongo/shell/query.js:78
```

`db.currentOp()` continues to return results similar to the above, even after the error has been reported. The log shows no errors at all (only lines indicating that this command is still running):

```js
2014-06-19T13:24:15.378-0400 [conn23]           M/R: (1/3) Emit Progress: 8400
```

Any ideas what could be happening here? Running MongoDB 2.6.2 on Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score -1):

At times putting some validation checks in the emit helps.
Wont Say Always helps.

But at times i faced this error, the issue was in the quality of values i was emitting.

Try running small chunks and check if it runs okay.